# Is it possible to use an existing google-services.json file for a new Xamarin.Forms app?

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin.forms, google-play-services

I am in the process of consolidating my iOS and Android apps into one code base using Xamarin.Forms. I am using Firebase to handle remote notifications for the apps in production. **I would like to use the same google-service.json and GoogleService-Info.plist files from my production apps in my new Xamarin project.** Is this possible? Or will I need to create and register a brand new application in Firebase?

I have already tried to copy the existing google-services.json file into my Xamarin project, however my app fails to initialize Firebase in the MainActivity.cs or the AppDelegate.cs.

I tried to create and register a brand new application in Firebase. When I copied the newly generated google-service.json file into my Xamarin project it worked. I understand that I *could* create and register a new app with Firebase but this is not what I want to accomplish. I want to use the functions and cloud messaging services I have already set up with my apps that are in production.

I expect to be able to use the existing google-services.json file and the GoogleService-Info.plist files from my production applications in my newly created Xamarin.Forms application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Firebase projects, on Android, an app is uniquely identified by a combination of its appication ID (sometimes called "package name") and a SHA-1 hash of the signing key.  If those things are the same in your new app, you don't have to change anything.  If either one of those things change, you'll need to create a new app.  It sounds like one of those things changed.

Answer (score 0):

As you said that you want to 'recreate' the apps (which should mean that the app family/bundle name remains the same), yes it should work. It is hard to say what you did wrong as many things could go wrong, perhaps try to make a simple plain new app in Xamarin and when you make it work understand what you did wrong.